# Adding Space Between DataList Rows

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, datalist

I have a datalist with the following attributes:

```
ID="uxDataList" runat="server" ItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="2px"
AlternatingItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" AlternatingItemStyle-BorderColor="Black" RepeatDirection="Vertical" 
AlternatingItemStyle-BorderWidth="2px" CssClass="OrderHistoryDataList" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="100%"
OnItemDataBound="uxDataList_OnItemDataBind" RepeatLayout="Table" GridLines="None"
```

Is there an attribute or css that I can use to put any sort of separation between the datalist **rows**? I want the layout to have borders around the item and the alternating item like I have but I want some sort of separation between the item and the alternating items of the list.

I've tried stuff like this css:

```
#mainContent table tbody tr { margin-bottom: 2em; }
```

this adds the padding/margin to the table row but there is no space between the borders of the item & alternating item

My datalist is set up like

```
<asp:DataList>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <table> </table>
        </div>
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div> </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <div>
            <table> </table>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Datalist>
```

Associated CSS:

```
.OrderHistoryDataList td { display:inline-flex; width:100%;}
.ImageDiv_OrderHistory { width:18%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; }
.DetailList_OrderHistory {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.DetailList_OrderHistory ul li { list-style-type:none; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;}
.DetailList_OrderHistory ul li:nth-child(3) { margin-top:10px; }
.OrderHistory_UnitPriceColor { color: #007f4b; }
.OrderHistory_ChargeAmountToDate { color: #B2B2B2; }
.OrderHistory_Total { color: #005CB8; }
.OrderHistory_DateLabel { font-size:large; font-style:italic; font-weight:bold; }
.OrderHistory_SmallerFont { font-size: smaller; }
.OrderHistory_MediumFont { font-size: medium; }
#mainContent table tbody tr { margin-bottom: 2em;}
```

Comment: This link might be helpful

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080797/aspdatalist-alternating-rows-style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I overlooked the fact that the `datalist` control has a `SeparatorTemplate` used to separate rows. I added this after the `ItemTemplate`

```
<SeparatorTemplate>
    <h4 class="OrderHistory_RowSeparator"></h4>
</SeparatorTemplate>
```

CSS Class:

```
.OrderHistory_RowSeparator { margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **CellPadding** to the datalist

```
<asp:DataList ID="uxDataList" runat="server" CellPadding="5" ...>
```

Comment: This adds the padding particular `tr` and `td` and pushes the cell down. It doesn't add space between the rows like I desire. I need them to be separated, not spaced apart. When I asked my question I thought those two would mean the same thing, they did not.

Comment: Then, I think your best option would be to use a **SeparatorTemplate** with some spacing element.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I answered my own question with that.